Pass buildkit flags to compose
Thanks to the --builder argument, it's easy to run docker compose with buildx.
How to pass buildx build arguments like --platform or --load?

There is no way to transfer a flag to a builder from a compose build command.
The only way of using the --load flag to the builder, is using the docker driver as describe here.
Unfortunately this driver does not support building multi-platform images.
However, according to the documentation, it should be possible to use the --load flag with the docker-container driver when the flag --driver-opt="default-load=true" is passed at the builder creation, but it does not work at least in my Docker version 25.0.1.
